# Salesforce Record type selection screen

Tags: record-type

how to hide a record type option from the "new record" pop up?

I have a custom object A from where if I click New Case in related list, user should be able to create a case. User has been given access to 2 case record types. I do not want record type pop up screen to show up for record type selection.
Based on a field let's say test A on object A , when new case is clicked it should decide which case record type to create based on the values of test a field.
If test A field on object is Mango then create Test1 case record type record
Else create Test2 Case record type.

So my question is, how can I hide these other record types from the pop up without restricting the users access to all  record types?

2/4/2024- Here is the formula  I used but I still do not see insurance policy record staying open.

```
/lightning/o/Case/new?recordTypeId=recordtypeID&defaultFieldValues=
Insurance_Policy__c={!InsurancePolicy.Id}
&backgroundContext=/lightning/r/InsurancePolicy/{!InsurancePolicy.Id}/view
```

Comment: are you willing to override the New button?

Comment: @cropredy Yes if that is the only way.

Comment: Remove the New button from the related list and replace with a "new" `New Case V2` button that is a URL; then use Lightning URL hack to define the recordTypeId to use - which can leverage SFDC formulas for conditional logic.  Make the `New Case V2` visible in the related list.  Work with this a bit and if you get stuck, use [edit] to show what you've tried and where you are stuck

Comment: @cropredy - I created the list button and added to the parent object. When I click the button I able to open new case record with record type id I passed and also lookup field is populated with value but it closes the original parent object record. this is the formula I used- /lightning/o/Case/new?recordTypeId=0123txxxxxxxx&defaultFieldValues=
Insurance_Policy__c={!InsurancePolicy.Id} ...how can I keep the insurance policy obejct record opened as is. It closes the window of insurance policy and just keep window of new case created.

Comment: In Classic, you would use `&retURL` but in Lightning, you use `&backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Insurance_Policy__c/{!Insurance_Policy__c.Id}/view`.  AS I said earlier, please use [edit] instead of comments to show the current state of your issue - it is so much easier for community users to help

Comment: @cropredy- I edited and added the formula I used but did not work. It still closes the insurance policy record on which the new button was place.